# Animation doesn't start instantly in iOS device - cn1

Tags: codenameone

The car flashes at the right before it starts animation. It works perfectly fine in android devices though. And the app icon is shown before the splash screen, which is not what I want. How can I make it work?

Have a look at the video [here](https://youtu.be/Z5E4hFsBdIg)

Code:

```
public void start() {
    if (current != null) {
        current.show();
        return;
    }
    showSplashForm1();
}

private void showSplashForm1() {

    Form splashForm = new Form(new BorderLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER));

    Container parentContainer = new Container(BoxLayout.y());
    splashForm.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, parentContainer);

    Label logoLabel = new Label(theme.getImage("logoMain.png").scaledWidth(screenWidth * 3 / 4));
    parentContainer.add(logoLabel);

    Label carLabel = new Label();
    Container carContainer = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    carContainer.add(carLabel);
    carLabel.setVisible(false); //added this line for iOS splash screenshots

    Image carImage = (Image) theme.getImage("car_static.gif");
    Timeline tcar = (Timeline) carImage;
    carLabel.setIcon(tcar);

    Label loadingLabel = new Label();

    Image loadingImage = (Image) theme.getImage("dots_min_time.gif");
    Timeline tloading = (Timeline) loadingImage;
    loadingLabel.setIcon(tloading);

    Container animateContainer = BoxLayout.encloseY(carContainer, loadingLabel);
    splashForm.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, animateContainer);

    Display.getInstance().scheduleBackgroundTask(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
                testDriveAndBookingAndContactStorage(splashForm);
        }
    });
    splashForm.show();
    splashForm.revalidate();

    //car animation starts
    carLabel.setX(-screenWidth);
    //carLabel.setVisible(true);
    carLabel.setVisible(BrowserComponent.isNativeBrowserSupported()); //updated

    carContainer.animateLayout(4200);

    splashForm.setTransitionOutAnimator(CommonTransitions.createFastSlide(CommonTransitions.SLIDE_VERTICAL, true, 500));
    new UITimer(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            carLabel.setHidden(true);

            if (Preferences.get(AllUrl.customerId, null) != null) {
              new Home(theme).show();
            } else {
                new LoginAndSignUp(theme, "").show();
            }
        }
    }).schedule(4200, false, splashForm);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The app icon splash is related to this: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2554
Notice you can create your own storyboard using xcode and replicate the first screen for a smoother launch experience.

I can't see the issue in the video but I'm guessing it's caused because of the screenshot process. You can confirm this by [disabling the screenshot process](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/no-more-ios-screenshots.html) and seeing if the issue is gone.

Assuming that's the case and you still want to keep the screenshot process you can do one of two things:

- Submit your own iOS splash screens as explained in the [iOS section in the developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/appendix-ios.html)
- Disable the animation during the splash screen generation process. You can detect that by checking if the native browser is supported which will return false only during splash screen generation

Comment: The app icon splash is due for 6.0 release. I think it will take time. Is there any immediate hacks. I want to release the app in appstore but not with app icon splash screen. Can't it be disabled?

Comment: 6.0 is the closest release. It doesn't mean we'll need to wait until the actual release. It would generally be fixed sooner. I suggest asking Steve in the issue tracker if there's an ETA for this.

Comment: the problem of app icon before splash screen is solved. I had ios.generateSplashScreens = false instead of ios.generateSplashScreens = true

Comment: You didn't see the issue in video so look at this video ( https://youtu.be/eibJ4qf3yUo ) for more clear view of my prob. At the right most bottom the image of a car appears and disappears before animation starts. How can I hide the image before animation starts? There is no issue in android though.

Comment: Android doesn't have splash screenshots. Just set the car to visible false if the native browser isn't supported.

Comment: Sorry I don't know why I deleted that line but adding the visibility to false doesn't solve the problem. See the video https://youtu.be/-o4lyxBQnCI The image flashes quickly at the bottom right before it starts animating.

Comment: You set it to false then a few lines later set it to visible true... That's not what I meant... You need it to remain invisible in the screenshot only if native browser is supported.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. What do you mean by "You need it to remain invisible in the screenshot only if native browser is supported."? If I dont set it to true afterward (ie. after form.show() method), the car image will not animate.

Comment: There are two separate things: Screenshot process & Runtime. During the screenshot process this needs to **always** be invisible. At runtime this needs to always be visible. You need one visibility statement: `carLabel.setVisible(BrowserComponent.isNativeBrowserSupported());`

Comment: I've replaced carLabel.setVisible(true) with carLabel.setVisible(BrowserComponent.isNativeBrowserSupported()) but it doesn't solve the problem. See the code in the question that I've changed

Comment: Download the IPA unzip it and see if the splash screen images contain the car. If they don't then that problem is resolved and the problem is something else. If they do then the problem is something else and I'll need a better way of understanding it

Comment: no they(default images and launch images of zipped ipa) don't contain car.

Comment: So the original problem is fixed. I'm guessing the current problem is that the animation started before the UI physically appeared. You can delay the start of the animation or start it from further away/give it more time.

Comment: I've used "carLabel.setVisible(BrowserComponent.isNativeBrowserSupported())" after splashForm.show(). And I think it means the carLabel will be visible after UI physically appears, isn't it? Setting the timer worked btw. Thanks

Comment: Set it before the show but both should work similarly.

Comment: If u create a project in old gui builder, there is beforeForm(), postForm(). Isn't before and after form.show() code work like that? I'm curious if the codes written above or below the "form.show()" doesn't matter anymore.

Comment: It matters in some cases. If you write after `show()` then `getCurrentForm()` will return the new form and some things will behave differently. However, since the UI is single threaded (like all modern GUI toolkits) when you invoke `show()` it only flips some states but doesn't actually do anything until you return the EDT thread back to us so we can physically paint the screen. So this might have impact on some things but not on everything